# How to filter mat chips in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, search, filter, tags

I'm doing angular project and I want to let the user search/filter from existing tags (mat-chips). I have a searchbox and I can filter a normal list but when I tried to do that for tags, I'm not sure how.

My mat chips inside home.component.html.

```
    <mc-tags [chips] = "tags" ></mc-tags>
```

My search box inside home.component.html

```
     <input matInput (input)="updateQuery($event.target.value)" class="input" >
```

the data inside list.ts

```
    export const tags = ['Google', 'Manufacturer'];
```

home.component.ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { users, tags } from './users.data';

@Component({
  selector: 'mc-explore',
  templateUrl: './explore.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./explore.component.scss']
})
export class ExploreComponent{

  query: string;
  users = users;
  tags = tags;

  updateQuery(query: string) {
    this.query = query;
  }
}
```

This is how it look like right now

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC1eB.jpg)

this is how I usually filter normal list/data

```
    <div [hidden]="!query">
    <div *ngFor="let name of users | search:query">{{ name }}</div>
    </div>
```

Stackblitz file without mc-tags since it's using from different components

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcklft

Comment: Can you create a stackBlitz to check it there?

Comment: @Tzimpo I just created it ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcklft ) but I didn't include <mc-tags> because it was using from different component. tx

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got the idea... you want the user to click on one chipe and filter the user arrays using the value of the selected chip, is that right?

Comment: @julianobrasil umm right now, I just want the user to search the chip in the searchbox and display the matched chip only and hide the rest. ( if you don't mind you can look at my attached picture)

Comment: Ok... you just want to start typing the name of the chip (tags) and filter them.

Comment: yes, exactly.. I can filter a normal list but not sure how to do that for chip.

Comment: Do you want to filter inside the mc-chips or outside it (mc-chips would receive the tags already filtered)?

Comment: sorry, I don't get what you saying but right now I'll be happy as long as I can filter the tags from the data.

Comment: inside your mc-tags component there's an input. But as you don't know what I'm talking about, I suppose that I don't have to mess with it and focus on the input outside mc-tags

Comment: @julianobrasil Thank you so much for helping me out and I'm just wondering how I can display like this " There are no result for {{what ever user text was }} " when there are no matched chip. I tried to use all the value from your code but I still can't make it work. tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what is described below.

**Change this:**

```html
<input matInput (input)="updateQuery($event.target.value)" class="input" >
```

**to this:**

```html
<input [formControl]="_inputCtrl" matInput class="input" >
```

**And change this:**

```html
<mc-tags [chips] = "tags" ></mc-tags>
```

**to this:**

```html
<mc-tags [chips]="_filteredTags" ></mc-tags>
```

**Add this code to your component typescript:**

```js
_filteredTags = [];

_inputCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

private _destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this._filterTags();

  this._inputCtrl.valueChanges
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$))
    .subscribe((value: string) => {
      this._filterTags(value);
      this.updateQuery(value);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  if (this._destroy$ && !this._destroy$.closed) {
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
  }
}

updateQuery(query: string) {
  this.query = query;
}

private _filterTags(filterValue?: string) {
  if (!filterValue) {
    this._filteredTags = [...tags];
    return;
  }

  this._filteredTags = this.tags.filter((v: string) =>
    v.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase().trim())
  );
}
```

---

**[UPDATE]:** I've put together this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflowcom-a-60857864-6433166?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. really appreciate it.